# Does Find My save multiple locations for the same name?

Tags: find-my

In the `Find My` app I can `Edit Location Name` e.g. when a person is at their school, I can set that location as having Location Name `School`.

However, the person in question goes to a university, and the campus is quite large. So, even if they are at school, they can be at quite different geographical locations.

I have tried to do `Edit Location Name` several times for this person, when they are at different places on the campus, each time setting the Location Name to `School`.

I haven't quite been able to figure out if Find My understands my intention. I want *all* of those locations to be called `School`, not just the last one I added.

So, does `Find My` keep track of several locations with he same name, e.g. `School`, or do previous locations become cleared when I edit a new place?

I have tried googling, and asking ChatGPT, but haven't been able to find a clear answer. ChatGPT sounds confident, but it always does. If you have an answer, please try to provide an authoritative source.